# How to set up dsetool authentication for Solr?

Tags: python, authentication, solr, datastax-enterprise

I've been playing around with and am new to Datastax Enterprise, and I was trying to use the dsetool create_core command to generate a Solr schema automatically for my table in Cassandra. I am using Datastax Enterprise 4.6.5.

I saw in the docs that there was authentication for dsetool using JMX or Kerberos. Right now, I'm using internal authentication, but dsetool asks for HTTP authentication if I try to run the create_core command.

I don't know anything about JMX or Kerberos, and I'm also new to Cassandra and Solr, so I have 3 questions.

1. Which protocol should I be using to be able to talk to Solr with authentication?
2. Can I or should I be using internal authentication at all if I use one of the two protocols above?
3. How does using one of these protocols change how I talk to Cassandra or Solr, for example, using the Datastax python connector or a Solr python client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because dsetool create_core is not supported with internal authentication, you can use the Solr HTTP API directly to create your core. Try something like the following from your command line:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=CREATE&name=<keyspace>.<table>&generateResources=true"
```

Comment: I believe there are some custom actions available in DSE Solr (i.e. `infer_schema`). One way I learned on how to know what does `dsetool` do - is to `strace` the command, extract the HTTP action, and then re-execute the action with `curl`/`wget`/etc.